# Why json_data.getString doesn't encode json string ? or its wrong?

Tags: java, android, json

I have the below error. I know I have to encode the result from string

```
07-08 21:26:51.348: E/2(22265): <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
07-08 21:26:51.353: E/Fail 3(22265): org.json.JSONException: Value 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I though the below will convert it . but still facing error.

```
 JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(json_data.getString("code"));
```

This is my code

```
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    System.out.println(result);
    Log.e(" 2",result );
}
    catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

        try
    {


            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(json_data.getString("code"));
            System.out.println("length="+menuObject.length());


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
```

this is php code

```
<?php
$host='mysql12.000webhost.com';
$uname='a6901827_moudiz';
$pwd='*****';
$db="a6901827_justed";


$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];


mysql_query('insert into samle values($id,$name)',$con);

print(json_encode("1"));


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Please I need to insert data in the database and return value.

Comment: If I were you, I would remove the host, username and db from your post.

Comment: @KenV.H. thanks for the advice but it just a free host and test database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the JSON String "1", but are trying to parse it as JSONObject.
A `JSONObject` in expects an actual JSON object that starts with `{` and ending with `}`. A string is a JSON value and not a JSONObject. That's why the `String` "1" cannot be converted to a `JSONObject`.

You could wrap the return value into a PHP Array:

```
array("value" => "1")
```

When you encode that into JSON, it will look like this:

```
{"value":"1"}
```

Then on the Java client, parse it as a JSONObject and get the string attribute that is named "value".

Or you could just parse it differently on the Java side. (by not using JSONObject).

Comment: then what should I replace this print(json_encode("1")); ?

Comment: I added the explanation to my answer.